# Return value of neighbor column

Tags: r

How can I find max value of column y (0.340), but return me same number position of column x (16.34)?

```
    x       y
17.98   0.035
18.03   0.098
17.35   0.123
16.34   0.340
18.97   0.090
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `which.max`

```
df1$x[which.max(df1$y)]
```

if we need the row

```
df1[which.max(df1$y),]
#     x    y
#4 16.34 0.34
```

Comment: I received a message "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" and I convert "as.data.frame". It´s works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @A.Hid.  It is because your dataset is a `matrix` (perhaps).  For matrix, use `df1[which.max(df1[,"y"]),]`